# Displaying search results using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm working on a project and I can't seem to make an API request to Node.js+MongoDB backend using AngularJS.

I have an api route instantiated as such:

```
app.get("/search_database/:queryString", function(req, res) { ... });
```

And I'm trying to build something on the frontend using Angular to display these results (in raw JSON) on the browser -- to no avail. API requests from the browser show what I want, but I want to be able to do the same with AngularJS.

Any guidance is appreciated! Thanks!

This is what I have so far:

*test.html*

```
<html ng-app="test">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script> src="core.js"</script>
   </head>

  <body ng-controller="searchCntrlr">
      <div>
      <input class="search-bar-input", ng-model="searchText"/>
      </div>

   {{results}}
   </body>


</html>
```

*core.js*

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.controller('searchCntrlr', $scope, $http) {
    $http.
      get('/search_database/:searchText/' + $scope.searchText).
      success(function(res){
        $scope.results = res.data;
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem -- a bunch of atrocious typos:

Corrected *test.html* (typo was in in the  for the core.js)

```
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="core.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body ng-controller="searchCntrlr">
    <div>
      <input class="search-bar-input", ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()"/>
    </div>

    {{results}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Corrected *core.js* (completely botched the app.controller syntax before)

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.controller('searchCntrlr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = function() {
    $http.
    get('/search_database/' + $scope.searchText).
    success(function(res){
      $scope.results = res;
    });

  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call you search on change like this:

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.controller('searchCntrlr', $scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = function() {
    $http.
    get('/search_database/:searchText/' + $scope.searchText).
    success(function(res){
      $scope.results = res.data;
    });

  }
};
```

and call this function in your template:

```
<input class="search-bar-input", ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()"/>
```

Or manually `$watch` your model and call search there.